# Iterating and concenating Typescript Types

Tags: typescript

```
const defaultThemeColors = {
    primary: [
        "#00000010",
        "#00000020",
        "#00000030",
        "#00000040",
        "#00000050",
        "#00000060",
        "#00000070",
        "#00000080",
        "#00000090",
    ],
    secondary: [
        "#FFFFFF10",
        "#FFFFFF20",
        "#FFFFFF30",
        "#FFFFFF40",
        "#FFFFFF50",
        "#FFFFFF60",
        "#FFFFFF70",
        "#FFFFFF80",
        "#FFFFFF90",
    ]
};
```

```
type ColorNums = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9";

type ThemeColors = {
    [x in keyof typeof defaultThemeColors]: string;
};
// "primary" | "secondary"
```

Thats what I was be able to:

```
type PrimaryType = `primary${ColorNums}`;
// "primary1" | "primary2" | "primary3" | "primary4" | "primary5" | "primary6" | "primary7" | "primary8" | "primary9"
```

But, I want to iterate theme colors with numbers and expect return like that:

```
"primary1" | "primary2" | "primary3" | "primary4" | "primary5" | "primary6" | "primary7" | "primary8" | "primary9" | "secondary1" | "secondary2" | "secondary3" | "secondary4" | "secondary5" | "secondary6" | "secondary7" | "secondary8" | "secondary9"
```

Is there any way to do it? Can it be done using mapped types and template literal types?

Comment: Well, if there is a bunch of colors how would do you handle it? That was I'm trying to do it.

Comment: I mean if you had tens of color types like "primary", would you define type for all of them? Isn't there solution to do it with TypeScript? Sorry, I'm trying to explain it clearly as much as I can.

Comment: Ah! I get it now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're **very** close. You just need to do the same thing with the names of the properties as you did with the `ColorNums`:

```typescript
type ColorNames = `${keyof typeof defaultThemeColors}${ColorNums}`;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKAVAFggWwQGEQMQAnCGAXhgG8AoGFmABwoEsCUKBPAFwwA2s1biARAGIADHPkBGGRIA0Y8S2nz5AJmVqNrLdpkBmfeo3HtAFguHNskwFZ7D6-IBsbwx7kB2HysnbQAOIMkQ+QBOIIBdA1YIBFAwOF5BEUtIgDE8-KVVbKMpfPy9IocYaTK880r3Utq7Bt8mstdW4Nqc7y7c2sD+kp7w4cce2K64xgBfAG5GKD42BBhScgoAOTQCajoJBQkYAB9qnWOziVNL6ptbiWcHzwf-B9CH6IlFpZW1vEIJDIlH2DEswgAHjBOGAYABrBB8EBIGDLVbI+DIdBYAFEDYguJCaBcMAAc0WC0YAHoqdUONwMg9kql0vwJIxfqt1sDtigiKCAAYAEnoCKRKLRCAxiFQmBw+DxPIgsxF+O2u2VAsWNPEAD0APyMIA)